# How to find substring in Python string

Tags: python

I have an list of strings as follows:

```
strings = [
  "On monday we had total=5 cars",
  "On tuesday we had total = 15 cars",
  "On wensdsday we are going to have total=9 or maybe less cars"
]
```

I want to be able to find and replace substring from those strings.

I can find and replace it as follows (If I have string with which I want to replace):

```
new_total = "total = 20"
for str in strings:
  new_string = re.sub(r"total\s?=\s?5", "{}".format(new_total), str)
  print(new_string)
```

In this case it matches only `total=5`. This is not what I want.

I want first to extract the `total = <value>` from a sentence, no matter if it has blank spaces before or after `=` sign, and then insert the extracted value into the other sentences

Thus something as follows:

```
some_sentence = "We will use this sentence to get total=20 of cars."
new_total = "????" // it needs to get total=20 
for str in strings:
  // Here I want to replace `total=<value>` or `total = <value>` in every str with new_total
  new_string = "????"
  print(new_string)
```

The **output** should be:

```
"On monday we had total=20 cars",
"On tuesday we had total=20 cars",
"On wensdsday we are going to have total=20 or maybe less cars"
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: It would help if you could explicitly state what you want to do: "I want to add spaces around the `=`-sign in `total = XXX`". Makes your question easier to understand with a fraction of the text.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I want to get substring from a sentence `some_sentence = "We will use this sentence to get total=20 of cars."` no matter if it has blank spaces before and after equal sign. And then add it in every string in list of string instead of `total = <value>` or `total=<value>`

Comment: Oh, so you first want to extract the `total = XXX` from a sentence, and then insert the extracted value into the other sentences? I get it now. But your question is horribly unclear IMO. You should try to clarify it. (As in, in the question itself, not in the comments.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Exactly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Instead of your hardcoded `5` use `\d+` in the regex:

```
import re

strings = [
  "On monday we had total=5 cars",
  "On thursday we had total = 15 cars",
  "On wendesday we are going to have total=9 or maybe less cars"
]

new_total = "total = 20"
for s in strings:
  new_string = re.sub(r"total\s?=\s?\d+", "{}".format(new_total), s)
  print(new_string)

# to extract the information you can use:
p = re.compile(r"(total\s?=\s?\d+)")
for s in strings:
  print( p.findall(s) )
```

Output:

```
On monday we had total = 20 cars
On thursday we had total = 20 cars
On wendesday we are going to have total = 20 or maybe less cars
['total=5']
['total = 15']
['total=9']
```

If you are sure you will have a match, you could also use `p.search(s).group(0)` (which will return the string instead of a list) instead of `p.findall(s)`.

Comment: Ok. But I want to get `total=<value>` from a sentence. `some_sentence = "We will use this sentence to get total=20 of cars."`. How can I get `total=20` from some_sentence?

Comment: @Aran-Fey the ``.*`` part can be usefull if you want the parts before and after the match to be accessible in separate groups. But I removed them, because they are really not neccessary here.